# neo4j cypher delete permutations in collection

Tags: collections, neo4j, cypher, permutation

I've a query in Neo4j/Cypher which returns a collection like that:

```
MATCH z = (a:X)-[b:Y*2..]->(a)
RETURN relationships(z)
```

It returns (the paths) respectively the names of the edges:

```
[name 1, name 2, name 3, name 5], 
[name 2, name 3, name 5, name 1],
[name 3, name 5, name 1, name 2],
[name 5, name 1, name 2, name 3],
[name 6, name 7],
[name 7, name 6],
[name 4, name 8],
[name 8, name 4]
```

In the result above the first 4 rows are equal, then the next two are equal and the last two rows are equal. I want to have no permutations like above i want something like that:

```
[name 1, name 2, name 3, name 5],
[name 6, name 7],
[name 4, name 8]
```

Does someone know how I would solve the problem?

Thanks in advance ;)

Answer (score 0):

Cypher does not have a direct way to sort a collection. But there's a way to do it: use `UNWIND` followed by a `WITH ... ORDER BY` for sorting on a row level and use `collect()` to aggregate again.

Your case is even more complex since you want to partially order things on a pre-path base. First you need to build a kind of hashsum for each path (we're here concating relationship's ids) then do the `unwind` followed by `order by` and a `collect` based on the hash calculated previously.

I assume you want to use `id` of your relationship for ordering.

```
MATCH z = (a:X)-[b:Y*2..]->(a)
WITH relationships(z) as rels, 
     reduce(s="", x in relationships(z) | s+x+"_") as hash
UNWIND rels as r
WITH hash, id(r) as r_id order by hash, r_id
WITH hash, collect(r_id) as sorted_r_id
RETURN distinct sorted_r_id
```